# How to access the same element of an array that has only one element or multiple elements?

Tags: php, arrays, api

I access an  API that returns an array of elements.

If there is only one element, it will return the array as:

```
Array {

   [response] => Array {

      [name] => Frank

   }

}
```

However, if there are multiple results, it goes one level deeper to account for each result:

```
Array {

   [response] => Array {

      [0] = > Array {

         [name] => Frank

      }

      [1] = > Array {

         [name] => John

      }

   }

}
```

This is quite frustrating as it means I have to first check if there is just one element or more than one, and then code each one separately.

Is there a better solution that automatically takes care of both scenarios (e.g. one result vs. multiple results) and always retrieves the name's that are available regardless ?

Comment: That sounds like a really annoying API design. Can you post the code sample you currently use?

Comment: You can modify the array returned from one result to structure it like the multiple result array, this way you only have to handle the response 1 way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either write an iterator that would deal with your *special case*, or you iterate over it an deal with the *special case*:

```
foreach ($array['response'] as $responses)
{
    isset ($responses[0]) || $responses = array($responses);
    foreach ($repsonses as $response)
    {
        # standard processing code per each item.
    }
}
```

*Special cases* can be very annoying, so take care of them early and ideally make them disappear.

Comment: Can you please explain what this line does:  `isset($responses[0]) || $responses[0] = $responses;` ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Programmer: if the `0` element is not set, create an array out of `$responses` first. That is what the expression in that line does. It deals with your special case that there is only one response.

Comment: @hakre Good response, though you seem to have a few typo's.

Comment: @ComFreek, Wasbazi: Thanks for pointing out. Quickly typed, if you see anything just edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

(If you can) Tweak the original API to always return the array with the indexed keys even when there are only one item in the array.

Else, add this one after you fetch the result from the API.

```
if(count($result['response'])==1) { $newResult['response'][0]=$result; }
else { $newResult=$result; }
```

Comment: How would I tweak an external API I do not control?  Is there some kind of pre-processing I can do?

Comment: If that is external, you cannot control it. so you have to use the second method I mentioned.